# What is this 2-3cm insect found in Slovakia?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Noted in the West Slovakia at the garden[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have with you a [Carpenter bee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpenter_bee), which are species of the genus *Xylocopa*  of the subfamily *Xylocopinae*

[Xylocopa violacea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylocopa_violacea), the violet carpenter bee, is the common European species of carpenter bee, and one of the largest bees in Europe. It is also native to Asia.

[image]

[image]

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XUs0l-YK68) is a link to a youtube video documentary about the bees.